# Упростить список/массив на python

Tags: python, массивы, строки, list

у меня такой список

```
[
    "[('djlf',", 
    '),', 
    "('j',", 
    '),', 
    "('Сало',", 
    ')]'
]
```

и его надо упростить до "djlf,j,Сало"

пробовал через `print(*list)`, но не получилось, список приходит с ms sql

```
dbCursor.execute("select Tovar from BazaMSK")
data = dbCursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: откуда берете список? может, проще пересмотреть его создание, чем теперь расковыривать нечто такое?

Comment: вам нужно упростить список до строки?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my_list = [
    "[('djlf',", 
    '),', 
    "('j',", 
    '),', 
    "('Сало',", 
    ')]'
]
```

Не оптимально и много букв, конечно, но так, чтоб был понятен механизм:

```
new_list = []
for word in my_list:
    tmp_str = ''
    for w in word:
        if w.isalpha():
            tmp_str += w
    new_list.append(tmp_str)
```

в `new_list` сейчас:

```
>>> new_list
['djlf', '', 'j', '', 'Сало', '']
```

и после:

```
new_str = ','.join(w for w in new_list if w)
```

в `new_str` будет искомый результат в виде строки:

```
>>> new_str
"djlf,j,Сало"
```

Answer (score 3):

День добрый! Как написали в комментариях, лучше пересмотреть место получение такого списка, но если хочется разобрать именно его. То можно для начала соединить все это в строку и распарсить с помощью json:

```py
data = [
    "[('djlf',", 
    '),', 
    "('j',", 
    '),', 
    "('Сало',", 
    ')]'
]

string_data = ''.join(data)
# "[('djlf',),('j',),('Сало',)]"
```

Это уже вполне валидная строка "Список кортежей".
Которую можно распарсить с помощью json и не больших доработок
парсера -> [ЗДЕСЬ ПОДРОБНЕЙ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15721641/16184934)

Answer (score 2):

Ну вот вам в одну строчку:

```
a = [
    "[('djlf',", 
    '),', 
    "('j',", 
    '),', 
    "('Сало',", 
    ')]'
]

res = ','.join(map(lambda x: x.split("'")[1], a[::2]))
print(res)
```

Вывод:

```
djlf,j,Сало
```

По шагам:

- Берём только чётные строки из списка
- Разбиваем эти строки по символу одиночной кавычки `'`
- Берём только второй элемент из каждой такой разбитой строки
- Соединяем полученные элементы через запятую в одну строку

Конкретно на примере ваших данных это работает. Но не зная остальных данных не поручусь, что будет работать везде, нужно проверять, возможно, механизм разбора должен быть другим, более универсальным.

Comment: в коде есть `a[::2]` на что интрепретатор говорит, нет ни какой переменной `a`.
Вопрос что за переменная `a`?

Comment: @Womba306 это имя вашего списка

Comment: спасибо, а сможешь помочь [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1295753/%d0%97%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%86%d1%8b%d1%84%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b5listbox-pysimplegui-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f]?

Comment: ```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\maksimov_dv\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\interface.py", line 19, in UpdateList
    res = ','.join(map(lambda x: x.split("'")[1], data[::2]))
  File "C:\Users\maksimov_dv\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\interface.py", line 19, in <lambda>
    res = ','.join(map(lambda x: x.split("'")[1], data[::2]))
AttributeError: 'pyodbc.Row' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: Да, что-то я погнался за одной строкой и забыл показать инициализацию списка. Добавил

Comment: Ну, значит в `data` у вас не совсем то, что в вопросе написано

Comment: у меня в data это вывод данных из ms sql и когда я изменял таблицу получилось другое

Comment: все работает с теми данными которые были `a = [
    "[('djlf',", 
    '),', 
    "('j',", 
    '),', 
    "('Сало',", 
    ')]'
]`