# Значения содержащие цифры/пробелы в списке(Listbox) PySimpleGUI не отображаються

Tags: python, sql-server, pysimplegui

у меня есть такой код

```
# импрорт
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pyodbc
from datetime import datetime

#настройки
connection = pyodbc.connect(("Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=MGP5-SPG04;Database=Test1;Trusted_Connection=yes;UID=sa;PWD=111qqqAAA"))
dbCursor = connection.cursor()
sg.theme('dark grey 9')
now = datetime.now()
Datatime = datetime.now()
print(datetime.now())

#получение списка товаров
def UpdateList():
    dbCursor.execute("select Tovar from BazaMSK")
    data = dbCursor.fetchall()
    new_list = ['']
    for word in data:
        new_str = ''
        for w in word:
            if w.isalpha():
                new_str += w
        new_list.append(new_str)
    new_str = ','.join(w for w in new_list if w)
    return new_list

#интерфейс
layout = [
    [sg.Text('Введите товар'),sg.Listbox(UpdateList(), size=(8,15), key='-KTovar1-'),sg.InputText(size=(50,6),key='-KTovar2-')],
    [sg.Text('Количество товара'),sg.InputText(size=(8,3),key='-KCountTovar-')],
    [sg.Output(size=(88, 20),key="-KInputText-")],
    [sg.Submit("Сохранить"), sg.Cancel("Обновить")]
]
window = sg.Window('Поставки', layout)

event, values = window.read()
while event not in (None,"Exit"):
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == "Сохранить":
        sql = 'EXEC [dbo].[BazaMSKInsert] @Tovar=?,@Count=?,@Data=?'
        params = (values['-KTovar2-'], values['-KCountTovar-'], Datatime)
        dbCursor.execute(sql, params)
        dbCursor.commit()
        print(params)
    if event == "Обновить":
        window['-KTovar1-'].update(values=UpdateList())
```

Думаю что проблема в `UpdateList()` его можно заменить на

```
res = ','.join(map(lambda x: x.split("'")[1], data[::2]))
print(res)
```

но тут я что-то не так написал

Comment: День добрый, а можете показать что у вас в `new_list`?

Comment: `['', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'aqdqdeqeq', 'dqdq', 'dsadadas', 'qweqw', 'qwer', 'qww', 'Stack', 'vzvz', 'Вода', 'куц', 'Мясо', 'Сало', 'тест', 'тесто', '', 'цыц', 'ыцыцыцыцц']` но в ms sql другие значения

Comment: @АндрейКоробейников,  `UpdateList()`  почему-то делает так что не считает цифры и пробелы

Comment: я почти уверен, что код работает на баге

Comment: я заменил 
`for w in word:
            if w.isalpha():`
на `for w in word:
            if w.isnum():`
и стали отображаться цифры, осталось добавить пробелы

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел проблему (str. isalpha() — Вернёт True, если в строке хотя бы один символ и все символы строки являются буквами, иначе — False.)

```
for w in word:
    if w.isalpha():
```

я нашел метод который проверяет на наличие специальных символов(кроме пробела)

```
def detect_special_characer(pass_string):
  regex= re.compile('[@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:]')
  if(regex.search(pass_string) == None):
    res = False
  else:
    res = True
  return(res)
```

и сделал

```
#Проверка на спец символ
def detect_special_characer(pass_string):
  regex= re.compile('[@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:]')
  if(regex.search(pass_string) == None):
    res = False
  else:
    res = True
  return(res)
#получение списка товаров
def UpdateList():
    dbCursor.execute("select Tovar from BazaMSK")
    data = dbCursor.fetchall()
    print(data)
    new_list = []
    for word in data:
        new_str = ''
        for w in word:
            if detect_special_characer(w)==False:
                new_str += w
        new_list.append(new_str)
    new_str = ','.join(w for w in new_list if w)
    print(new_list)
    return new_list
```

Все стало работать
решение нашел на

> [https://coderoad.ru/19970532/Как-проверить-строку-на-наличие-специального-символа#62941655](https://coderoad.ru/19970532/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0#62941655)

Comment: Честно говоря не понял для чего все это, ведь из базы вы получаете уже готовый список товаров и можно сразу его как результат возвращать или там есть какие-то спец символы которые вы не желаете видеть? Но если так нужно, красивей будет вместо `if detect_special_characer(w)==False` вставить  `if not detect_special_characer(w) `

Answer (score 0):

```py
# Здесь вы посимвольно проверяете строку и
#  если символ из "списка спец символов" вы его не пропускаете
for w in word:
    if detect_special_characer(w)==False:
        new_str += w
```

Но ф-я detect_special_characer у вас для того что бы определять
*есть ли в строке спецсимволы*. Проще применять для проверки на вхождение символа в строку или список *(любой итерируемый объект!)* оператор `in`
(Например `a in ['a','b','c'] => True`)

Поэтому можно упростить ваш код до следующей функции:

```py
def UpdateList():
    dbCursor.execute("select Tovar from BazaMSK")
    data = dbCursor.fetchall()
    special_chars = '[@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:]'
    new_list = []
    for word in data:
        new_str = ''.join([ w for w in word if w not in special_chars ]) # Очищаем строку от лишних симвоов
        new_list.append(new_str.strip()) # Добавляем строку в список обрезая пробелы
    return new_list
```