# Обновление списка из Таблицы ms sql через PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, sql-server, pysimplegui

у меня есть такой код

```
# импрорт
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pyodbc
from datetime import datetime
import re


#настройки
connection = pyodbc.connect(("Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=MGP5-SPG04;Database=Test1;Trusted_Connection=yes;UID=sa;PWD=111qqqAAA"))
dbCursor = connection.cursor()
sg.theme('dark grey 9')
now = datetime.now()
Datatime = datetime.now()
print(datetime.now())


#Проверка на спец символ
def detect_special_characer(pass_string):
  regex= re.compile('[@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:]')
  if(regex.search(pass_string) == None):
    res = False
  else:
    res = True
  return(res)
#получение списка товаров
def UpdateList(Output):
    dbCursor.execute(f"select {Output} from BazaMSK")
    data = dbCursor.fetchall()

    new_list = []
    for word in data:
        new_str = ''
        for w in word:
            if detect_special_characer(w)==False:
                new_str += w
        new_list.append(new_str)
    new_str = ','.join(w for w in new_list if w)
    for i in range(len(new_list)):
        new_list[i]=new_list[i].lower()
    return new_list
#TovarANDCount=[]
#for i in  range(len(UpdateList("Tovar"))):
    #TovarANDCount.append(UpdateList("Tovar")[i],UpdateList("Count")[i])
print(UpdateList("Count"))#Тут ломаеться
#интерфейс
layout = [
    [sg.Text('Введите товар'),sg.Combo(UpdateList("Tovar"), size=(40,15), key='-KTovar1-')],
    [sg.Text('Количество товара'),sg.InputText(size=(8,3),key='-KCountTovar-')],
    [sg.Output(size=(88, 20),key="-KInputText-")],
    [sg.Submit("Сохранить"), sg.Submit("Обновить")]
]
window = sg.Window('Поставки', layout)

event, values = window.read()
while event not in (None,"Exit"):
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == "Сохранить":
        sql = 'EXEC [dbo].[BazaMSKInsert] @Tovar=?,@Count=?,@Data=?'
        params = (values['-KTovar1-'], values['-KCountTovar-'], Datatime)
        dbCursor.execute(sql, params)
        dbCursor.commit()
    if event == "Обновить":
        window['-KTovar1-'].update(values=UpdateList("Tovar"))
        window['-KTovar1-'].update(values=UpdateList("Tovar"))
        print("Обновляем данные,", datetime.now())
```

но тут я что-то не так написал выдает ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\maksimov_dv\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\interface.py", line 45, in <module>
    print(UpdateList("Count"))
  File "C:\Users\maksimov_dv\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\interface.py", line 35, in UpdateList
    if detect_special_characer(w)==False:
  File "C:\Users\maksimov_dv\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\interface.py", line 21, in detect_special_characer
    if(regex.search(pass_string) == None):
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

подскажите как решить

Comment: Еще раз приветствую. Есть выражение дословно не помню, но текст примерно такой: "Если вы пытаетесь решить проблему с помощью регулярных выражений, то вы получаете еще одну проблему". А смысл байки следующий: используйте регулярки только в крайних случаях, для вашей проблемы я дал ответ в вашем прошлом вопросе. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1295878/241444

Comment: он просто не работает

Comment: я в какой-то момент перестал понимать, почему у меня краши и я не могу вывести нормально данные

Comment: @АндрейКоробейников, ваш код работает аналогично моему
Такая же ошибка

Comment: Скорей всего None приходит на проверку в  `detect_special_characer()`.

Comment: там не None, проверка на приход None проходит в sql, там не стоит галочка напротив `Allow Nulls`

Comment: [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wtoU_qbndkl6yZDJm-820VgXrFxs5qpZ/view?usp=sharing] так выглядит sql server

Answer (score 0):

Я переписал весь код

```
# импрорт
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pyodbc
from datetime import datetime
import re
import pandas


#настройки
connection = pyodbc.connect(("Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=MGP5-SPG04;Database=Test1;Trusted_Connection=yes;UID=sa;PWD=111qqqAAA"))
dbCursor = connection.cursor()
sg.theme('dark grey 9')
now = datetime.now()
Datatime = datetime.now()
print(datetime.now())


#Проверка на спец символ
def detect_special_characer(pass_string):
  regex= re.compile('[@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:]')
  if(regex.search(pass_string) == None):
    res = False
  else:
    res = True
  return(res)
#получение списка товаров

def UpdateList(sql):
    dbCursor.execute(sql)
    data = dbCursor.fetchall()
    new_list = []
    for word in data:
        new_str = ''
        for w in word:
            if detect_special_characer(w)==False:
                new_str += w
        new_list.append(new_str)
    new_str = ','.join(w for w in new_list if w)
    for i in range(len(new_list)):
        new_list[i]=new_list[i].lower()
    return new_list

#TovarANDCount=[]
#for i in  range(len(UpdateList("Tovar"))):
    #TovarANDCount.append(UpdateList("Tovar")[i],UpdateList("Count")[i])
#print(UpdateList("Count"))
print(pandas.read_sql_query(    "SELECT top 100 * FROM [dbo].[BazaMSK]"))
#интерфейс
layout = [
    [sg.Text('Введите товар'),sg.Combo(UpdateList('Select Tovar from BazaMSK'), size=(30,15), key='-KTovar1-'),sg.Text('Введите производителя'),sg.Combo(UpdateList('EXEC [dbo].[Proiz_Select]'), size=(30,15), key='-KProiz-')],
    [sg.Text('Количество товара'),sg.InputText(size=(8,3),key='-KCountTovar-')],
    [sg.Output(size=(88, 20),key="-KInputText-")],
    [sg.Submit("Сохранить"), sg.Submit("Обновить")]
]
window = sg.Window('Поставки', layout)
event, values = window.read()
while event not in (None,"Exit"):
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == "Сохранить":
        sql = 'EXEC [dbo].[BazaMSKInsert] @Tovar=?,@Count=?,@Data=?,@IdProiz=?'
        params = (values['-KTovar1-'], values['-KCountTovar-'], Datatime, (values['-KProiz-'].split())[1])
        dbCursor.execute(sql, params)
        dbCursor.commit()
        print("Добвленно",values['-KCountTovar-'], values['-KTovar1-'],"в",(values['-KProiz-'].split())[0])
    if event == "Обновить":
        window['-KTovar1-'].update(values=UpdateList('Select Tovar from BazaMSK'))
        window['-KProiz-'].update(values=UpdateList('EXEC [dbo].[Proiz_Select]'))
        print("Обновляем данные,", datetime.now())
        print(UpdateList('EXEC [dbo].[BazaMSK_Select]'))
```

sql:

```
USE [Test1]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[BazaMSK_Select]    Script Date: 17.06.2021 10:24:51 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[BazaMSK_Select]

as 
SET NOCOUNT ON
SELECT [Tovar]+' '+Cast([Count] as varchar) as Tovar
  FROM [dbo].[BazaMSK]





SELECT [Tovar]
      ,[Count]
      ,[SaleID]
      ,[Data]
      ,[IdProiz]
  FROM [dbo].[BazaMSK]
```

```
USE [Test1]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[BazaMSKInsert]    Script Date: 17.06.2021 10:25:08 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[BazaMSKInsert] 
(
@Tovar nvarchar(255),
@Count int,
@Data datetime,
@idProiz bit
)
as
SET NOCOUNT ON


DECLARE @SaleId int
Select @SaleId = (Select Max(SaleId) from BazaMSK) + 1

If (Select Count(*) from BazaMSK Where Tovar = @Tovar) = 0 
  begin

  INSERT INTO [dbo].[BazaMSK]
           ([Tovar]
           ,[SaleID]
           ,[Count]
           ,[Data]
           ,[IdProiz])
     VALUES
           (@Tovar
           ,@SaleID
           ,@Count
           ,@Data
           ,@IdProiz)
END
ELSE BEGIN
   Update BazaMSK Set [Count] = [Count] + @Count WHERE Tovar = @Tovar
END
```

```
USE [Test1]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[BazaMSKInsert]    Script Date: 17.06.2021 10:58:46 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[BazaMSKInsert] 
(
@Tovar nvarchar(255),
@Count int,
@Data datetime,
@idProiz int
)
as
SET NOCOUNT ON


DECLARE @SaleId int
Select @SaleId = (Select Max(SaleId) from BazaMSK) + 1

If (Select Count(*) from BazaMSK Where Tovar = @Tovar) = 0 
  begin

  INSERT INTO [dbo].[BazaMSK]
           ([Tovar]
           ,[SaleID]
           ,[Count]
           ,[Data]
           ,[IdProiz])
     VALUES
           (@Tovar
           ,@SaleID
           ,@Count
           ,@Data
           ,@IdProiz)
END
ELSE BEGIN
   Update BazaMSK Set [Count] = [Count] + @Count, IdProiz = @idProiz WHERE Tovar = @Tovar
END
```

и все стало работать